# SharePoint designer 2013 can't open SharePoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, error, login

When I try to open SharePoint Site, it looks like SharePoint designer tries to load something, then nothing happens. No errors.

My SharePoint designer 2013 used to open this site fine before something went wrong.

Other sites are opening fine.

1. My SPD has SP1(kb2817441) and kb3114337 updates.
2. Host OS is Windows 10.
3. I installed SharePoint designer 2013 with all updates to other PC, it works fine.
4. I tried to clean all SharePoint designer caches. I reinstalled SPD, it didn't help.

Comment: what is the template of the site you are trying to open ? Is it a team site or publishing site or any other ?

Comment: This could be caused with Modern Authentication enabled on your tenant. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/security-and-compliance/enable-modern-authentication?view=o365-worldwide#disable-modern-authentication-on-devices

Comment: @GautamSheth It is classic team template

Comment: @LukasNespor I no have "EnableADAL" in Registry key. I tried add "EnableADAL"=0 and "Version"=1. It doesn't helped. (

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible, your site is in Modern layout, classic is turn off by the administrator.
Or, your organization could have some policy to block it.

Check this options. 
You are trying with site collection or sub-site ?